# How to change the sytem highlight color in a windows form in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, colors, textbox, highlight

Is there a way to change the "default windows system blue" highlight color in all the controls in a windows form?

Including textbox, datetimepicker and all of them.

Thank you.

**Edit**
The highlight color is when a user select the text inside the control, normaly it's blue.
Can't change the system highlight color and don't want to. 
I'm interested especially on 3 controls: TextBox, DateTimePicker and NumericUpDown.

Comment: It is a system setting, it affects all programs.  Ask at superuser.com if you want to know how to change it.  You'll have to tell them what Windows version you use.

Comment: I can't make change to the system, i don't want to either. I just want to change it in my windows form.

Answer (score 0):

By all controls I'll assume you mean all of them that would normally have a highlight color... You simply use the `SelectionColor` property of highlight-able controls.

For example, it can be used like this:

```
RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Aqua;
```

This would set the highlight color of the RichTextBox to Aqua. If you however wanted all controls to be highlighted... You would have to override their drawing and force them to redraw while the mouse is clicked and dragged over the area which they reside.

Comment: I don't want to highlight all the controls. I don't want to select any control. I want to change the highlight color when a user select text, the system default is blue. The `RichTextBox.SelectionColor` change the text background color, not the highligted.

Comment: Windows forms has no method for changing the highlight color for all controls in the form with one command... It must be done for each control.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you tell me how to make it for a textbox and a datetimepicker please?

Comment: With `DateTimePicker` you can use `CalenderTitleForecolor` it can be changed programmatically, but is also available in the properties but is not considered a highlight color... And unfortunately the textBox's highlight color cannot be changed... It's hard-coded to the system setting, and has no method to change this color in the current version of .NET

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look for external controls.